# Issue while inserting data to elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to learn how to use tools like logstash, redis, elasticsearch and Kibana.

I have successfully completed the configuration of the tools logstash, redis, elasticsearch and Kibana. Read a log file and was able to insert it correctly into elastic search.

Now my aim is to use Java and store a string to elasticsearch. I have configured elastic search running on the same machine (Linux Ubuntu).

The code used is as follows:

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                        .put("client.transport.sniff", false).build();

Client client = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("192.168.160.242", 9300));

                //Convert to JSON and index
                IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
                        .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                                    .startObject()
                                        .field("user", "kimchy")
                                        .field("postDate", new Date())
                                        .field("message", "trying out Elastic     Search")
                                    .endObject()
                                  )
                        .execute()
                        .actionGet();
```

But while taking the elastic search console, I am observing the following error:

```
[2014-01-02 14:00:20,410][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Kine, Benedict] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xaa3df382, /**192.168.160.242:38045** :> /**192.168.160.242:9300**]], closing connection
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:27)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

its very random suggestion but did you set up elasticsearch with custom claster name? if yes, maybe try to add it to settings then?

Comment: I tried changing the cluster name to 'abcd', but after changing the name, I observed that the logstash shipper was taking the cluster name as 'abcd' while logstash indexer was still taking it as 'elasticsearch' (the default name of cluster). Moreover, since I have specified "client.transport.sniff" as false, I understand that this shouldn't cause any issue. Please note that I have configured all this in the same Ubuntu machine. Everything is on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

check the version of java client you are using and elasticsearch server.

as per [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html#transportclient) guideline they should same

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by putting the cluster name instead of client.transport.sniff" as false

To see your current cluser_name:

```
curl -XGET hostname:port/_cluster/nodes?pretty=true
```

and create connection using

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
    .put("cluster.name", "test").build();
Client client = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("hostname", port));
```